# variables getting modified in parallel region when using debug mode

Tags: c++, openmp, icc

In the following code I am importing a mat file which contain a 4D matrix using matlab libraries and perform some calculations after circular shifting the 4D matrix in the mat file. Here when code  is compiled in release mode it works fine without any problem for all the values of **m** ( m is the value which determines the shift amount when circular shifting the matrix). In debug mode the code only works when m = 0 else I get a memory access violation error.

```
#include "mat.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>
#include "readmat.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <valarray>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <ctime>
#include "omp.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

typedef struct {
    size_t X;
    size_t Y;
    size_t U;
    size_t V;


} DataIn;

inline float getelement(DataIn data, int x, int v, int u, int y, double * __restrict dataElements)
{
    int index = data.X*data.Y*data.U*(v)+data.X*data.Y*(u)+data.X*(y)+x;
    return (float)dataElements[index];
}


int main()
{
    const clock_t begin_time = clock();
    int i;
    double start, end,start1;

    start1 = omp_get_wtime();
    int elements;
    int numberofdimension;

    const char *file = "Bracelet.mat";
    const size_t* dimepointer;
    Mat out;

    try{
        readmat thismat(file);
        numberofdimension = thismat.getnumbrofdimensions();
        dimepointer = thismat.dimensionpointer();



        cout << "The dimensions are  ";
        for (int k = 0; k < numberofdimension; k++)
        {
            cout << *(dimepointer + k);
            cout << "  ";
        }
        elements = thismat.numberofelements();

        // Dimensions
        DataIn data;
        data.X = *(dimepointer);
        data.Y = *(dimepointer + 1);
        data.U = *(dimepointer + 2);
        data.V = *(dimepointer + 3);

        double* dataelements;
        dataelements = thismat.getarraypointer();

        float*  __restrict image = new float[data.U*data.V];
        int m = 1;

        int X_shift, Y_shift;
        //omp_set_dynamic(0);
        omp_set_num_threads(4);
        start = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel
        {
            float temp_sum;
            int id = omp_get_thread_num();
            int num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
            std::cout << "thread is " << id << endl;

            for (int v = 0; v < data.V; v += num_threads)
            {
                for (int u = 0; u < data.U; u++)
                {
                    temp_sum = 0;

                    for (int y = 0; y < data.Y; y++)
                    {
                        Y_shift = y*m;

                        for (int x = 0; x < data.X; x++)
                        {

                            X_shift = x*m;
                            if ((v + id) < Y_shift && u < X_shift){
                                temp_sum += getelement(data, x, (data.V - (Y_shift - (v + id))), (data.U - (X_shift - u)), y, dataelements);


                            }


                            else if ((v + id) >= Y_shift && u < X_shift){
                                temp_sum += getelement(data, x, ((v + id) - (Y_shift)), (data.U - (X_shift - u)), y, dataelements);

                            }

                            else if ((v + id) < Y_shift &&  u >= X_shift){
                                temp_sum += getelement(data, x, (data.V - (Y_shift - (v + id))), (u - (X_shift)), y, dataelements);

                            }

                            else if ((v + id) >= Y_shift && u >= X_shift){
                                temp_sum += getelement(data, x, ((v + id) - (Y_shift)), (u - (X_shift)), y, dataelements);

                            }


                        }

                    }
                    //#pragma omp critical
                    {
                        *(image + (u*data.V) + (v + id)) = temp_sum / (data.X*data.Y * 255);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        cout << "data is" << endl;
        for (int t = 0; t < 15; t++)
            cout << image[t] << " ";

        cout << "The end of array \n FINISHED\n";


         end = omp_get_wtime();
        std::cout << "\n The wall time algo: " << (end - start)<<endl;
        std::cout << "\n The wall time: " << (end - start1) << endl;
        out = Mat(data.U, data.V, CV_32FC1, image); //create an image

        if (out.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
        {
            cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        std::cout << float(clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;




        imshow("Refocused Image", out); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

        waitKey(0);  //wait infinite time for a keyress

        destroyWindow("Refocused Image"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"*/




        cout << endl;
        cout << "This is the number of dimensions  ";
        cout << numberofdimension << endl;

        cout << "The array elements ";
        cout << elements;
        cout << endl;

        for (int n = 0; n < elements; n++)
        {
            //cout << *(arraypint + n);
            //cout << " ";
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "ERROR:"<< e.what() << endl;
    }


    //cin >> i;
    return 0;

}
```

when the code is at **#pragma omp parallel** the values of structure **DataIn** are correct ( This structure contains the dimensions of the 4D  matrix) as shown in the following figure.

[image: The DataIn data variable when program hits the break point at #pragma omp parallel]

However after the parallel section this structure is modified with some values. Within this region this structure isn't modified and this happens only in **debug mode when** **m is not equal to 0**

[image]

This code works in release mode without any problem and use Intel c++

Comment: Problem was resolved. Intel parallel studio gave a warning on race condition and then after declaring X_shift and Y_shift  inside the parallel region problem was no longer there. Still wonder why it was only broken in debug mode

Comment: In release mode those variables are stored in CPU registers and not really shared (OpenMP allows such temporary inconsistency in its memory model). In debug mode register optimisation is turned off and you experience the data races in their full glory.